# Are Android Wear Node IDs Unique

Tags: android, wear-os

Are Android Wear Node ids unique (is it safe to store a node's id as a reference to a specific wear device)?

If not, is there a unique way to identify a specific wear device?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the id is unique, although I would think you would normally just use Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes() to find the wearable. Maybe it depends on what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: I use getConnectedNodes to find wearables, but I want to persist certain preferences on a per wearable basis.

Comment: Hi Eliezer. Have you found the right unique ID for android wearables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32697247/1718223

Answer (score 3):

Android Wear node ids are based on UUIDs, which should be unique, according to the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html