# Uniquely identify Android Wear device

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

What would be the best way to uniquely identify a specific Wear-device? I'd like to store a preference *per device* on the phone and thus need an identifier that is static. I would expect that the [`NodeId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node.html#getId()) is assigned dynamically (and changes after each reconnect, or after each reboot, for example).

Comment: I was performing some tests in one of my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24964564/3827276 and it seems that the nodeId is static. Of course it would be nice to get a confirmation about that, but from my tests it seems to stay unchanged after reboots.

Comment: +1 to Maciej. NodeId is static in my experience

Comment: Perfect, thanks for letting me know, Maciej and Garf1eld! You're welcome to submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working with a couple of Sony SmartWatch 3 devices and needed to reset some of them to factory settings. It turned out that the NodeId changed quite significantly from a rather long one (such as 738eaa61-703a-4dcb-ae93-d1f326e0c6d1) to a relatively short one like ed806f56.

However, as long as I didn't reset the watch completely I did never experience a change in the NodeId and it should be a reliable value (after a reset, the Watch needs to be paired again with the phone anyway).